# How to initialize a list of a class type received as a parameter?

Tags: java, generics, initialization

I am a beginner in Java.

How do I initialize a list of a class type received as a parameter? I have a method that takes in a `Class<?>` argument as a parameter, and I want to create a list of this class type.

```
public List<?> returnList(Class<?> listItemType) {
    //create a list of type "listItemType"
    //populate the list
    //return the list
}
```

I have tried doing

`List<listItemType> list = new ArrayList<listItemType>()`

but VSCode shows `listItemType cannot be resolved to a type`.

I have also tried `<? extends listItemType>`, `<listItemType.getName()>` and the below code, but they don't seem to work either.

```
Object obj = listItemType.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
List<obj.getClass()> = new ArrayList<obj.getClass()>();
```

Comment: Make the method generic. `public <T> List<T> returnList(Class<T> listItemType) {return new ArrayList<T>();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the method a generic method with a named type parameter it will work.  For example:

```
public <T> List<T> returnList(Class<T> listItemType) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        list.add(listItemType.getConstructor().newInstance());
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
        // do something
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note that various exceptions are possible.  For example, the class may not have a suitable constructor, constructor may not be accessible, or it may throw exceptions.  A complete version of this method should do something appropriate, or declare the relevant exceptions so that they can propagate to the caller and beyond.

Without the *named* type parameter `T` you don't connect the wildcard in `List<?>` to the wildcard in `Class<?>`.  So the compiler wouldn't know that `returnList(Foobar.class)` is intended to return a `List<Foobar>`.

And there is no way that you can use the variable name `listItemType` as a class name as in `List<listItemType>`.   That's why you were getting "listItemType cannot be resolved to a type".  Variable names and type names are in different Java namespaces.

Your attempt `<? extends listItemType>` fails for the same reason, and
`<listItemType.getName()>` fails because an expression is not a type.

Another way to think about those failed attempts is that they use runtime values (e.g. the value of `listItemType`) to do compile time type checking.  That implies that the compiler needs to be able to look into the future to see what the runtime values are *going to* be.  Clairvoyance is not a feature of current generation Java compilers :-).

Comment: Makes sense. I have practically no experience with Java, hence the concept of having Object and Class classes seemed unintuitive. Nonetheless, it makes sense that runtime values can't be used for compile time type checking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

> Generic methods allow type parameters to be used to express
> dependencies among the types of one or more arguments to a method
> and/or its return type.

This is a full example:

```
public class NewMain {

    private static class Foo {

        public Foo() {
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<Foo> foos = returnList(Foo.class);
        System.out.println(foos.get(0));
    }
    
    public static <T> List<T> returnList(Class<T> listItemType) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            T obj = listItemType.getConstructor().newInstance();
            list.add(obj);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return list;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If I am interpreting it correctly, this returns a list which accepts objects of the Class class, and the returned list will contain a single object, which is the class passed as the parameter.

Comment: But I want a list which accepts the objects of the class `listItemType`. If I call `returnList(int.class)`, I want a list of integers.

Comment: Please note that if the provided class doesn’t have no args constructor them the new instance call will throw exception and the returned list will be empty